# Why do we use 'T' when we are to say matrix-vector product?

Tags: mathematics, linear-algebra

On the first picture author uses $T$ meaning matrix-vector product

[image]

But other website do not use $T$, but says that $x$ is a vector, I do not understand if it is important or not

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a vector or matrix has the superscript $T$, it means the matrix/vector is [transposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose).

Transposing a matrix or vector means flipping the matrix along its diagonal, that is, changing the elements such as the columns are rows and the rows are columns.

For instance:

[image: transpose]

When speaking about vectors, we normally understand them as column vectors. This means that a vector with $n$ elements is a matrix of dimensions $n \times 1$.

When two bidimensional matrices $A$ and $B$ are multiplied ($A \cdot B$), the second dimension of $A$ must match the first dimension of $B$. Therefore, if $A$ is a vector of dimensions $n \times 1$ and $B$ is a matrix of dimensions $n \times m$, to compute $A \cdot B$, we need the vector $A$ in transposed form to get the dimensions right, that is, $A^T B$.

On the other hand, if $A$ is a matrix of dimensions $n \times m$ and $B$ is a vector of dimensions $m \times 1$, then we don't need to transpose $B$ to compute $A \cdot B$, because the dimensions already match.